# Do Z80 datalines need termination

Tags: hardware, z80

If I am using a z80 can you just tie all data lines to the ROM 28c16 or do they need termination via 10k ohm resistors to ground?

Comment: No. works fine without - even plug board wiring will do it unless you go for some 40+ MHz.

Comment: @Raffzahn distance has a lot do do with it too.  For components on the same board you can probably do without.  But I remember with the S100 bus, the difference between a good system and a bad one was often the quality of the termination.

Comment: There's just something wrong. 10k pull-down might not be called termination. If you need termination because of signals echoing around on a long  bus, 10k would definitely be useless. If by termination you simply mean if a bus wire should be held in idle state by weak resistor, then 10k might be fine. But as we don't know if your Z80 is an NMOS or CMOS device, we can't know what value is good, and whether a pull-up is more correct than a pull-down. So can you clarify which exact Z80 CPU model you mean, and do you mean terminations for reflections or just pull resistors?

Comment: @Justme You are completely right about the "pull-up/down" vs "reflection" distinction. It doesn't help that the Shugart floppy drive bus used the same resistor pack on the last floppy drive as pull-up and parallel termination at the same time. The Shugart floppy drive bus uses open-collector drivers, so a pull-up resistor is required for the bus to operate at all. The pull-ups were quite low (330 Ohm?) and positioned at the receiving end (on the controller for "input" signals, on the last drive for "output" signals) and doubled up as termination to reduce reflections.

Comment: @MarkRansom Of course it has. Then again the questions does not seem to be about a 22 slot open end S100 board potentially with 10 or more boards plugged and cranked up to 8+ MHz., or does it?

Comment: @Raffzahn I just wanted to make sure your comment had some context around it - as with most things, it depends.

Answer (score 2):

In a typical small CPU system, you don't need any pullups or pulldowns on the data bus at all. The CPU will only read the data from the bus exactly at the time someone else (other chip like ROM, RAM or IO) puts data there, being accessed by CPU. Likewise, other chips shall read data from the bus only when being selected for write by the CPU outting data on the bus. The state of the bus between reads and writes doesn't matter to any of the devices connected to it.

There could be however exceptions:

1. When you'd like to have non-populated memory or IO areas read back as all ones or all zeros, you might install pull ups/downs. However, if you have some TTL logic connected to the data bus (like 74xx/74LSxx/74ALSxx/74Fxx/.. but *NOT* 74HC/74AC/..) note that their inputs are already pullups and 10k pulldowns might be way too not enough to park bus to all zeros. So it is recommended, in the presence of such TTL devices, to park bus at all ones.
2. When you pump a special kind of bus, like above mentioned S100 or some other, requiring strong outputs and heavy pullups (which act partially as terminators). But in this case you would need bus drivers (like '245 devices) anyway and still no need to pullup/down the CPU data bus pins.